# Loading VMware virtual machine configuration in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vmware

When I select to *File* -> *Open* in VMware and browse to *Virtual Machines* -> *Ubuntu 64-bit*, I find there are two VMware virtual machine configuration files. Is there any reason for this? Can I delete one of them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file named Ubuntu 64-bit (1) is a copy of the file named Ubuntu 64-bit. Right-click each of the files and select *Properties* -> *General* tab. If the two files are duplicates they will both be exactly the same size. Rename the Ubuntu 64-bit (1) file to Ubuntu 64-bit (1).bak. You can delete the Ubuntu 64-bit (1).bak file after a few months if nothing in VMware breaks.